# Ошибка в подключении БД Mysql к отчету FastReport,как вывести отчет?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, .net-6, fastreport

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MySqlDataConnection));
        Report report = new Report();
        MySqlDataConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlDataConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=home.olele.ru;database=ipopo;uid=ipopv;password=2110;";
        //Вот здесь вылетает ошибка ,нет такого метода CreateAllTables();
     
        sqlConnection.CreateAllTables();
     
        report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(sqlConnection);
        report.Load("D:\\KylinarMarket\\KylinarMarket\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\invoice.frx");
     
        report.Prepare();
        // Вообще правильно ли так выводить в Listbox ls?
        ls.Items.Add(new Frame()
        {
            Content = report,
        });
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(System.String)'.
   at FastReport.Data.MySqlDataConnection.GetDBObjectNames(String name, List`1 list)
   at FastReport.Data.MySqlDataConnection.GetTableNames()
   at FastReport.Data.DataConnectionBase.CreateAllTables(Boolean initSchema)
   at KylinarMarket.Windows.ReportViewWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\KylinarMarket\KylinarMarket\Windows\ReportViewWindow1.xaml.cs:line 57
Вызвано исключение: "System.MissingMethodException" в FastReport.Data.MySql.dll
```

Помогите вывести отчет ,если кто то работал с этим и знает как ,работаю на Net Core 6.0 WPF BD MySQL

Comment: Вставьте ошибку текстом вместе с трассировкой стека. Вместо `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` напишите `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` и скопиройте вывод исключения из окна "Вывод"/Output студии.

Comment: aepot Доброе утро! Нашел ошибку в  StackTrace = "   в FastReport.Data.MySqlDataConnection.GetDBObjectNames(String name, List`1 list)\r\n   в FastReport.Data.MySqlDataConnection.GetTableNames()\r\n   в FastReport.Data.DataConnectionBase.CreateAllTables(Boolean initSchema)\r\n   в KylinarMarket.Windows.Rep...

Comment: нужна полная трассировка, не в комментарий, а в сам вопрос. Просто скопируйте текст из окна вывода.

Comment: Добавил ,помогите решить эту ошибку с конектом,уже какой день с конектом к отчету пытаюсь сделать

Comment: Выглядит так что FastReport несовместим с установленной версией MySql.Data. Пробовать обновить либо то, либо другое.

Comment: Понял пробую сейчас

Comment: И это, пароль от базы данных поменяйте, текущий вы слили в сеть.

Comment: Да я поменять не могу,так как учитель мне такой назначил,но полный пароль в сеть я не слил ,вырезал

Comment: Ну тогда все ок

Comment: А вы с отчетами сталкивались? и если да как реализовывали?

Comment: Нет, я не сталкивался. Просто мне понятен смысл исключения, которое вы показали.

Comment: Вот и пробую с версиями играть )) У FastReport есть FastReport.Data.MySql и они видимо не ладят с  FastReport хотя версии одинаковые свежие

Comment: Смысл в том что библиотека FastReport пытается вызвать конструктор класса MySqlConnectionStringBuilder в указав string в качестве аргумента. Но у нет такого конструктора в библиотеке MySql.Data, что очень странно. Согласно [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnectionstringbuilder-ctor(system-string)), он есть во всех версиях библиотеки.